# Careers invitation page styling issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, user-interface

It looks like there are some styling issues on the careers invite page.

[image: example of styling problems]

1. The send invitation button is misaligned
2. The send invitation button is too close to the email address text box
3. there's no vertical padding between the form and "previously sent invitations"

This can be fixed (technically, not necessarily saying it's the right way) by doing the following things

1. Changing the element containing the button from a `<p>` to `<div>` which gives you the `margin-left` style.
2. Add an empty label to fix the vertical alignment (likely the simplest way, debatable if hacky or not)

Below is the html explained above to help you (though clearly i removed my personal link and replaced with `#`)

```
<div>
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send Invitation">
  <a class="hide" href="#" id="never-mind">OK, never mind</a>
</div>
```

Which gives you this appearance, which is good, but the button still looks slightly off center. The next header is still too close, but I'll leave that up to you to decide how to space that.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**@Darren** This has been fixed. Sorry for the headache it may have caused. Also I appreciate the suggestions you posted. In the end, the solution I went with was to update the layout based on our new grid system and pushing the input button down with  `margin-top: 2em`.

I've also increased the spacing between sections to `4ems`.

Comment: awesome, thanks, and no headaches caused, so it's all good :)